# How can I place a couple of html elements on the map?

Tags: openlayers-2

I need to place html elements for drawing in it some text and graphic by [Raphaeljs](http://raphaeljs.com/).

Is it possible?

I'am trying to create an empty marker for each visible feature and then erase icon container and place into it raphael canvas:

```
var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers('Markers');
map.addLayer(markers);

var size = new OpenLayers.Size(1, 1);
var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(0, 0);
var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/i/b.gif', size, offset);

var marker_items = {}, current_items = {}, centroid, x, y, key, marker, $marker;

layer4.events.register('moveend', layer4, function(e){
    current_items = {};
    for (var i=0, n=layer4.features.length; i<n; i++) {
        centroid = layer4.features[i].geometry.getCentroid(); 
        x = centroid.x, y = centroid.y;
        key = 'll-'+x+'-'+y;
        current_items[key] = true;
        if (marker_items[key])
            continue;

        // create new marker and store it in hash by key
        marker_items[key] = new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(x, y), icon.clone());
        markers.addMarker(marker_items[key]);

        // erase icon container, add canvas, and draw raphael graphics
        $marker = $(marker_items[key].icon.imageDiv).empty();
        $canvas = $('<div class="chart-canvas"></div>').appendTo($marker);
        Raphael($canvas.get(0), 70, 70).piechart(35, 35, 35, [55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10]);
    }

    // remove markers that not visible
    for (i in marker_items) {
        if (!current_items[i]) {
            markers.removeMarker(marker_items[i]);
            delete marker_items[i];
        }
    }
});
```

I have successfully draw graphics, but maybe there is more simple way?

Comment: Can you provide more context on what you're trying to achieve and what have you done so far to get to that goal?

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this with adding a div in your body tags.

```
    <div id="graphic"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

than you can change it with this way:

```
OpenLayers.Util.getElement("graphic").innerHTML = yourGraphicElement
```

i hope it helps you....